# GWT compiler can't find sources of depending module in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, gwt, intellij-idea, requestfactory, gwt-compiler

I'm using IDEA 117.216

It would be great if [CrazyCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104891/crazycoder) sees this question :)

How do you guys reference another module so GWT compiler sees it ?

*When I say **module** I mean module in IntelliJ IDEA's terminology.*

Here is my situation. I have midside project (GAE + GWT + RequestFactory). Now I created Android module in my project. The idea is that it will use [C2DM](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/) and talk to the server via RequestFactory (RF).

So naturally I created 3rd module within my project and moved all RF proxies and interfaces there so I can reference it both from GWT/GAE module and Android module.

Android module likes it, but GWT compiler doesn't. It can't find classes that I moved to "shared" module. Giving me errors such as:

```
[ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/work/sideprojects/courierapp/src/com/blah/courierApp/client/admin/AdminPage.java'
[ERROR] Line 77: No source code is available for type com.blah.shared.proxies.OrderProxy; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[ERROR] Line 81: No source code is available for type com.blah.shared.factories.AdminRequestFactory; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

I need to note that **SharedClasses module is added as dependency for GWT module.** But still GWT doesn't know where its sources are.

It seems to me it's **[this bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-80724)**.

How do you solve this ? I don't really want to have two steps of compilation: build shared classes jar with sources first, then build GWT project that references that jar and etc...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's more like [IDEA-67661](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-67661) where the responsible developer explains why it is so:

> IDEA 10 indeed includes to the classpath source roots from **modules
>   with GWT facets only**. This ensures that unneeded directories aren't
>   added to the classpath. Also you need to have a GWT Facet in a module
>   to enable GWT-specific completion and inspections in it...

Comment: **AWESOME!!!** Adding GWT facet to that module did the trick. You rock, man! Спасибо большое :)

Answer (score 0):

You must let `.java` files in the module. GWT compiler works with them, not with `.class` files.

Comment: I know. How can I do that in IDEA in my case?