# RequestFactory fails with "UnexpectedException: No RequestContext for operation LPZEK7DlYkoG1$NQ5MjHlmuRChk="

Tags: android, gwt, annotations, gwt2, requestfactory

Could you guys please help me why I'm having this exception?

I extracted RequestFactory proxies and context interfaces into separate jar so I can use it both in GWT client and Android client (details are **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10185057/gwt-compiler-cant-find-sources-of-depending-module-in-intellij-idea)**)

Unfortunately RF throws an exception on the server in very first call. The exception is:

```
com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.UnexpectedException: No RequestContext for operation LPZEK7DlYkoG1$NQ5MjHlmuRChk=
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerDecorator.die(ServiceLayerDecorator.java:216)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ResolverServiceLayer.resolveRequestContext(ResolverServiceLayer.java:154)
```

Below is my factory interface. As you can see I had to replace `Service` annotations with `ServiceName` because I didn't want to compile all custom locators with Guice injections to jar that will go on mobile devices.

```
public interface AdminRequestFactory extends RequestFactory
{
    // @Service(value = UserServiceDao.class, locator = InjectingServiceLocator.class)
    @ServiceName(value = "com.blah.courierApp.server.dao.UserServiceDao", locator = "com.blah.courierApp.server.inject.InjectingServiceLocator")
    public interface GaeUserServiceContext extends RequestContext
    {
        public Request<String> createLogoutURL(String destinationURL);
        public Request<GaeUser> getCurrentUser();
    }

    // @Service(value = OrderDao.class, locator = InjectingServiceLocator.class)
    @ServiceName(value = "com.blah.courierApp.server.dao.OrderDao", locator = "com.blah.courierApp.server.inject.InjectingServiceLocator")
    public interface OrderRequestContext extends RequestContext
    {
        Request<List<OrderProxy>> listAll();
        Request<Void> delete(Long id);
        Request<Void> createOrder(OrderProxy order);
        Request<OrderProxy> findOrderById(long id);
        Request<Void> updateOrderState(long id, StateType newStateType);
    }

    GaeUserServiceContext contextUserService();
    OrderRequestContext contextOrder();
}
```

When I compiled it RF Annotation Tool gave following warning:

```
Cannot fully validate context since domain type com.blah.courierApp.server.dao.UserServiceDao is not available.
You must run the ValidationTool as part of your server build process.
Add @SuppressWarnings("requestfactory") to dismiss.
```

So when the exception thrown under the debugger on the server I see that instance of   `com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.vm.impl.Deobfuscator` has empty `operationData` field which is being initialized by `DeobfuscatorBuilder` class that was generated by RequestFactory annotation tool.

So... I decompiled that class and found this:

```
public final class AdminRequestFactoryDeobfuscatorBuilder extends Deobfuscator.Builder
{
  public AdminRequestFactoryDeobfuscatorBuilder()
  {
    withRawTypeToken("w1Qg$YHpDaNcHrR5HZ$23y518nA=", "com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.EntityProxy");
    withRawTypeToken("8KVVbwaaAtl6KgQNlOTsLCp9TIU=", "com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.ValueProxy");
    withRawTypeToken("FXHD5YU0TiUl3uBaepdkYaowx9k=", "com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.BaseProxy");
    withRawTypeToken("5vjE9LUy$l0uvi4kMYpS3JA1WEE=", "com.blah.shared.model.GaeUser");
    withRawTypeToken("8KVVbwaaAtl6KgQNlOTsLCp9TIU=", "com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.ValueProxy");
    withRawTypeToken("5a7OV4PSV$1xemsooKLfEQ4g5yY=", "com.blah.shared.proxies.OrderProxy");
    withRawTypeToken("neR_xIhE5oZsc0HbnkAMa8A88yw=", "com.blah.shared.proxies.OrderStateProxy");
    withRawTypeToken("t6gMQWDROJnYvqYhNURV8pd$sn4=", "com.blah.shared.proxies.OrganizationProxy");
    withRawTypeToken("1o45xgS$5bIkBKF4wlR8oMw_FSo=", "com.blah.shared.proxies.PersonProxy");
    withRawTypeToken("FXHD5YU0TiUl3uBaepdkYaowx9k=", "com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.BaseProxy");
  }
}
```

It didn't generated tokens for factory. Therefore there are no calls to `Deobfuscator.Builder.withOperation` because of which my server can't find context when calls comes from the client.

**Questions are:**

- Why doesn't RequestFactory Annotation Tool generate tokens for factory (operations) ?
- How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it was pretty tricky... But debugging in RF Annotation Tool helped :)

Turns out you **have to** have domain classes that you refer to in `@ServiceName` in classpath of RF Annotation Processor. It creates chicken-and-egg problem. You have to compile `SharedClasses` module to compile main module but you have to compile domain classes from main module to compile `SharedClasses` module.

Here is what I did:

- Disabled RF annotation processing for SharedClasses module.
- In RF annotation processor **of main module** I explicitly specified RF factory that has to be processed using parameter `rootOverride = com.blah.shared.factories.AdminRequestFactory`

It sucks that I have hardcoded full qualified class name in project settings though.

If you guys know more elegant method please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I too hit the same problem. Basically I have 3 GWT modules 1. Main module and in the second module I have the requestFactory, server domain classes and the client side proxy values. I am pretty much sure that your solution is what I need to put in place. However I am confused how to specify the rootOverride in the maven build phase. Any pointers in the structure of pom.xml would be immensely helpful.

Comment: I suggest removing this post, as it's obviously not an answer (You can post it as an answer though).